# How can I find all "((" and replace them with "("?

Tags: java

I'm given a string, and I want to replace all open parenthesis that occur in succession, with a single one

- `((5))` → `(5)`
- `((((5))))` → `(5)`

I tried

```
str = str.replaceAll("((", "(");
```

and got regex patttern error
then i tried

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\((", "(");
```

then i tried

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\((", "(");
```

I keep getting the same error!

Answer (score 4):

have you tried this?

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\({2,}", "(");
```

The '\' is the escape character, so every special character must be proceeded by it. Without them, regex reads it as an open parentheses used for grouping and expects a closed parentheses.

Edit: Originally, I thought he was trying to match exactly 2

Comment: @AndrewBoarders Now I got a new error, "Invalid escape sequence..."

Comment: This does not work if there are 3 successive parentheses. The result will be 2 parentheses

Comment: You changed your answer for the 3d time because it did not work and now you have  the code from @Andreas 's comment!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape each parenthesis and add `+` to account for successive occurrences:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\(\\(+","(");
```

Comment: Instead of using `+`, you could also use `replaceAll("\\({2,}","(")`, i.e. match 2 or more open-parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the parentheses don't need to be paired, e.g. `((((5))` should become `(5)`, then the following will do:

```
str = str.replaceAll("([()])\\1+", "$1");
```

*Test*

```
for (String str : new String[] { "(5)", "((5))", "((((5))))", "((((5))" }) {
    str = str.replaceAll("([()])\\1+", "$1");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

*Output*

```
(5)
(5)
(5)
(5)
```

*Explanation*

```
(         Start capture group
  [()]      Match a '(' or a ')'. In a character class, '(' and ')'
            has no special meaning, so they don't need to be escaped
)         End capture group, i.e. capture the matched '(' or ')'
\1+       Match 1 or more of the text from capture group #1. As a
          Java string literal, the `\` was escaped (doubled)
```

```
$1        Replace with the text from capture group #1
```

See also [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GgAGim/1) for demo.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer +1 for the test case

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the brackets are fixed or dynamic but assuming they may be dynamic what you could do here is use `replaceAll` and then use `String.Format` to format the string.

Hope it helps

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){

    String str = "((((5))))";
    String abc = str.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)","");
    abc =  String.format("(%s)", abc);
    System.out.println(abc);

 }
}
```

**Output:** (5)

I have tried the above code with `((5))` and `(((5)))` and it produces the same output.